# Counting the number of occurrences of a string

Tags: string, excel, counting

11/21, 12/5, 12/6

11/21, 12/5, 12/6

11/15, 12/5

11/15, 11/21

11/21, 12/5, 12/6

Given a set of 5 cells that each contain a row of this information as a string, what would be the best way to count the number of occurrences of one of the dates? I got lost in the excel functions and need a recommendation.

Comment: [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried countif - I've used =countif(A1:A5, "11/15"), but it produced 0. I also tried to be more specific and used =countif(A1:A5, (find("11/15", A, 1) > 1)) to try to search within the cell to see if there was an occurence of the string, but I knew it wasn't the right function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND("12/6",A1:A5),0), 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNT(IF(FIND("12/5",A1:A5),1))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.